# Keras is unable to intialize

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to intialize withe the parameters but i get the error of "*init*() got an unexpected keyword argument scale"

I am working on Neural collaborative filtering with keras and cannot initialize my parameters.

```
import theano
import theano.tensor as T
import keras
from keras import backend as K
from keras import initializers
from keras.regularizers import l1, l2, l1_l2
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Lambda, Activation
from keras.layers import Embedding, Input, Dense, merge, Reshape, Merge, Flatten, Dropout
from keras.optimizers import Adagrad, Adam, SGD, RMSprop
from evaluate import evaluate_model
from Dataset import Dataset
from time import time
import sys
import GMF, MLP
import argparse

#################### Arguments ####################
def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Run NeuMF.")
    parser.add_argument('--path', nargs='?', default='Data/',
                        help='Input data path.')
    parser.add_argument('--dataset', nargs='?', default='ml-1m',
                        help='Choose a dataset.')
    parser.add_argument('--epochs', type=int, default=100,
                        help='Number of epochs.')
    parser.add_argument('--batch_size', type=int, default=256,
                        help='Batch size.')
    parser.add_argument('--num_factors', type=int, default=8,
                        help='Embedding size of MF model.')
    parser.add_argument('--layers', nargs='?', default='[64,32,16,8]',
                        help="MLP layers. Note that the first layer is the concatenation of user and item embeddings. So layers[0]/2 is the embedding size.")
    parser.add_argument('--reg_mf', type=float, default=0,
                        help='Regularization for MF embeddings.')                    
    parser.add_argument('--reg_layers', nargs='?', default='[0,0,0,0]',
                        help="Regularization for each MLP layer. reg_layers[0] is the regularization for embeddings.")
    parser.add_argument('--num_neg', type=int, default=4,
                        help='Number of negative instances to pair with a positive instance.')
    parser.add_argument('--lr', type=float, default=0.001,
                        help='Learning rate.')
    parser.add_argument('--learner', nargs='?', default='adam',
                        help='Specify an optimizer: adagrad, adam, rmsprop, sgd')
    parser.add_argument('--verbose', type=int, default=1,
                        help='Show performance per X iterations')
    parser.add_argument('--out', type=int, default=1,
                        help='Whether to save the trained model.')
    parser.add_argument('--mf_pretrain', nargs='?', default='',
                        help='Specify the pretrain model file for MF part. If empty, no pretrain will be used')
    parser.add_argument('--mlp_pretrain', nargs='?', default='',
                        help='Specify the pretrain model file for MLP part. If empty, no pretrain will be used')
    return parser.parse_args()

def init_normal(shape, name=None):
    return initializers.normal(shape, scale=0.01, name=name)
```

Error:

> TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'scale'

Comment: well, does the thing you're initializing actually have an argument scale? because the error message thinks otherwise.

Comment: but when i take out the scale argument i still get some errors.

Comment: maybe you get different error and now it can be problem with different argument or something totally different - so first read carefully error message.

Comment: I tested `initializers.normal` and it doesn't use `scale` nor `name`, only `shape`

Answer (score 0):

`initializers.normal` doesn't contain the arguments `name` and `scale`. Only `shape`.